# How to parse data from a xml into a table and make it update changes live

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I have stumbled upon a bit of a issue and I'm hoping that I can get some help/pointer here how to overcome it. 
I have an external xml file that I need to parse and display in the table. I did this. 
The issue is that the file is updating every second, so I would like the data in the cells to update "live" as well, according to the changes in xml file. 
The problem is that I don't know what should I use to do it. Can anyone please point me into right direction.

```
<?php
require('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('http://admin:admin@192.168.1.108/status.xml');
foreach($html->find('response') as $row) {
     $frontdoorlock = $row->find('led1',0)->plaintext;
     $reardoorlock = $row->find('led2',0)->plaintext;
     $fronthandle = $row->find('btn0',0)->plaintext;
     $frontdoor = $row->find('btn1',0)->plaintext;
     $rearhandle = $row->find('btn2',0)->plaintext;
     $reardoor = $row->find('btn3',0)->plaintext;
     $temperature = $row->find('temp0',0)->plaintext;
     $humidity = $row->find('humid0',0)->plaintext;
     $currentdate = $row->find('temp2',0)->plaintext;
     $lastpowered = $row->find('temp3',0)->plaintext;
}  
?>
<div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Cabinet Name
                    </td>
                    <td >
                        Front Door Lock
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Front Handle
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Front Door
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Rear Door Lock
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Rear Handle
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Rear Door
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Temperature
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Humidity
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Current Date
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        System Last Powered
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Cab1
                    </td>
                    <td >
                        <?php if($frontdoorlock == "0") echo "CLOSED";
                              else echo "OPEN";
                        ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php if($fronthandle == "0") echo "CLOSED";
                              else echo "OPEN";
                        ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php if($frontdoor == "0") echo "OPEN";
                              else echo "CLOSED";
                        ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php if($reardoorlock == "0") echo "CLOSED";
                              else echo "OPEN";
                        ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php if($rearhandle == "0") echo "CLOSED";
                              else echo "OPEN";
                        ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php if($reardoor == "0") echo "OPEN";
                              else echo "CLOSED";
                        ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $temperature; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $humidity; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $currentdate ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $lastpowered ?>
                    </td>
               </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a front-end framework like [angularJs](https://angularjs.org/) that supports data binding? Data-binding is incredibly powerful and I feel like it would be the perfect solution for your problem. Here's a quick [video demonstrating it](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-binding).

You can bind your output table to a variable that represents that data, which updates each second according to the XML.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wan't to change the logic of the page itself ... like doing everything with javascript. You can simply put a:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="15">
```

meta tag in your HTML ... then the browser will update the page every X seconds (being the CONTENT value).

This being the simplest solution for the current situation.

But I would highly suggest to do this with JavaScript. There a tons of frameworks that will do the hard stuff for you.

My personal favourite: [VueJS](http://vuejs.org/)

Comment: I'm happy to change whole of the code if that will make it work. At the moment I'm just stuck and not sure where to go with it. <br> I can't refresh the whole page I need just the cells (data in them) to be refreshed (updated).